# Pixel 2 XL multi function dock, or fitted sleeve

Tags: smartphones, case, docking-stations

I have a Pixel 2 XL preordered which is intended to be a development and testing workhorse which will be connected to all sorts of devices in vehicles, at desks, in the field.  I need a dock for it.

All of the ports I need are included in devices like [this dock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074CYBT6Z).  USB 3.1 Type C gen2, Gigabit ethernet, SD card slot, 2 or more USB 3.0 ports, HDMI, PD pass thru charging.
[image: dock without sleeve/cradle]
The problem with this product is that I do not want to carry it around plugged into my phone dangling from the USB port.  The dock and phone need to join to be carried as a single brick.  I need either

a) a dock with these features specifically designed to cradle the Pixel 2 XL body, not just its USB port.  Also, add a 3.5mm audio jack to the list of ports.

or

b) a dumb Pixel 2 XL cradle which I can attach to the above or similar dock with epoxy.  Once mounted and plugged in, I would then mold sugru around the USB cord and allow it to cure.  This should result in a DIY equivalent to a).

Has anyone seen or heard of either of these?  If not, chances are this will get someone started developing one.

Comment: Adhesive velcro? Or, for b) just about any phone case once they come out for the Pixel. There will surely be rugged ones as well

Comment: A normal phone case is probably not an option unless it is easily and quickly removable without loose parts while its back remains stuck to the dock.  I will also want to be able to quickly put the phone in a car mount by itself.  I'd rather not stick adhesive velcro directly to my $1k phone.  Its OK for the dock to look hacked together as it will already be ugly with cables, but the phone should be able to be returned to stock state.

Comment: I've had two Goosperry Jelly cases and they fit quite tightly. Too bad they dont seem to be available for the Pixel 2 XL yet. And as any rubber case - they have no loose parts. Although usually during removal the back bends slightly which might be an issue.